# Ext: news: hide "showinpreview" in Backend

Tags: typo3, tx-news

How can i hide the field "showinpreview" in the backend?
I want to hide this checkbox for the editor and always choose the first image as the teaser list image.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To hide this field in the backend form, you can use this Page TSconfig:

```
TCEFORM.sys_file_reference.showinpreview.disabled = 1
```

To always activate this field for new records, add this Page TSconfig:

```
TCAdefaults.sys_file_reference.showinpreview = 1
```

Quick reminder: *Page TSconfig* has to be written in your **page properties** because it configures the TYPO3 backend. It's not part of the 'normal' TypoScript which is solely responsible for the frontend.